# How to overlay the projectitem icon in SolutionExplorer?

Tags: .net

I have developed a visual studio addin. One of my requirements is to programmatically change the icon of a project item in the solution explorer or rather overlay the current icon .How can we achieve this?(as if we see when a file is checkedout)